# Determine the time that a git commit is pushed to a remote branch (e.g., origin/master)

Tags: git

Within git, a commit is time stamped with the time that the commit was generated on the local machine. Though this timestamp has uses, for my purposes this value will not work.

Rather, I need to determine the time that the commit is merged/fast-forwarded into the remote branch.

My first attempt was to use the time found by executing: git reflog origin/master --date=local

This partially works, but it does not give information about the full set of commits for all authors.

Comment: What is your use case? Git doesn't log this type of information as it isn't relevant to the history of the code, but we might be able to help you find another option.

Comment: I want to be able to aggregate commits into groups that were pushed within X time of each other so that I can perform fairly lengthy tests on the group rather than on each individual commit.

Comment: Time is usually a poor delineator for testing. Usually topic or user is better. Do you use any kind of feature branching model?

Comment: It has to be time because I'm coordinating commits with another repo. I'm not in a position to change the infrastructure around these repos.

Answer (score 1):

Commits operate in a way that is very similar to books. A book is published, and every copy after that is an instance of that book. It's easy to determine if a copy is authentic and it's easy to determine when the original was published. Unfortunately it is much harder to determine when any given copy was purchased and almost impossible to determine the last time it was read.

Your best bet is to use the electronic equivalent of a receipt or a card catalog. You could use a hook to log push transactions which will allow you to cross reference pushes with commits and use that to look up the information, but git does not provide this information natively.